# how to restrict ssh-agent to trusted applications only?

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

Is there a way to prevent an application from using my ssh-agent keys?

I started using an application that uses ssh to access my remote server (possibly for a legitimate reason, according to the application developers, but not a good reason, according to me).  I found out when the shell where I started the application from asked me for my RSA key passphrase.
The first few times I didn't even know because the key was already in my ssh-agent, so the application quietly used it and ran commands on my remote server without my knowledge.

I don't want this application to use my ssh keys behind my back.
I take a certain amount of risk by downloading and running an application, but beyond this risk, I take additional privacy and security precautions like using an ssh passphrase.  ssh-agent seems to remove the RSA passphrase security, so that the passphrase protects me only when I'm not logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ssh-add` has switch `-c`, which makes the added keys subject to confirmation before use. From man `ssh-add`:

> **-c**      Indicates that added identities should be subject to confirmation before being used for authentication.  Confirmation is performed by `ssh-askpass(1)`.  Successful confirmation is signaled by a zero exit status from `ssh-askpass(1)`, rather than text entered into the requester.

It should suit your needs.

Comment: I'll try it, but I use ssh a lot and the prompts may annoy me.  I'll also try aliasing the "eager-to-ssh" program so it does ssh -D first:  alias prog='ssh -D; prog'.

Comment: I've adopted this.  The prompts are easy to get by.  Just press the Enter key.  I've also added ssh -D to the alias for the program in question so the ssh prompts don't come up and annoy me.